# MS Access - Find duplicate values by concatenating some columns

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a table with 5 columns. I need to find duplicate values using the first 3 columns.

Here is an example of my dataset:

[image]

Here is the output I need:

[image]

Here is the script that I tried to use:

```
select 
    count ([Tracking id] as [Count],
    [Hierarchy], 
    [Requirement ID], 
    [Tracking ID2], 
    [Status]
From 
    [table 1]
group by
    [Hierarchy], 
    [Requirement ID], 
    [Tracking ID2], 
    [Status]
having 
    count ([Tracking id]) > 1
```

Obviously this is not going to work because you can't group [Tracking ID2] and [Status].

I need a work around that would work in MS Access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `subquery` to achieve this

```
select 
    [Tracking id],
    [Hierarchy], 
    [Requirement ID], 
    [Tracking ID2], 
    [Status]
from
 [table 1] 
where [Tracking id] in (
     select 
       [Tracking id]
     From 
       [table 1]
     group by
       [Tracking id]   
     having count ([Tracking id]) > 1)
```

**or**

```
 where exists (
         select 
           1
         From 
           [table 1]
         group by
           [Tracking id]   
         having count ([Tracking id]) > 1)
```

to include count(), this is one of the options, by using `join`

```
  select 
        t1.ct,
        t1.[Tracking id],
        [Hierarchy], 
        [Requirement ID], 
        [Tracking ID2], 
        [Status]
  from [table 1] t
  inner join
    (select 
        [Tracking id],
        count(1) as ct
    from [table 1]  
    group by [Tracking id]   
    having count ([Tracking id]) > 1)) as t1 on t1.[Tracking id] = t.[Tracking id]
```

Comment: @metal Is there a way to add a count function to your script. I tried to modify your script to include Count ([Tracking ID]) and got an aggregate error message.

Comment: @metal Could you comment this script? My script did not yield the same result as you. I would like help in improving my script.

 'SELECT 
  count([Tracking ID]) AS [Count], 
  [hierarchy],
  [tracking ID], 
  [requirement ID]
  [tracking ID2], 
  [status]
 FROM 
  [table 1]
 GROUP BY 
  [hierarchy],
  [tracking ID], 
  [requirement ID]
  [tracking ID2], 
  [status]
 HAVING count([Tracking ID]) >1
 ORDER BY count([Tracking ID]) DESC;'

Comment: yes, because the count will be based on `GROUP BY [hierarchy], [tracking ID], [requirement ID] [tracking ID2], [status]`, not only for `tracking id`

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want:

```
select [Hierarchy], [Requirement ID], min([Tracking ID2]) as [Tracking ID2], min([Status]) as status
From [table 1]
group by [Hierarchy], [Requirement ID] 
having count(*) > 1;
```

`status` should not be in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: I cited in my post that I need [Status] and [Tracking ID2] in my results. I am aware that 'status' should not be there. 
I am here to asking for work around.

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 . . . I did miss that `[Tracking ID2]` also needs to be aggregated and not a `GROUP BY` key.